# не работает date-fns

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date-fns

пишу на фреймворке vue.js

делаю `import { format } from 'date-fns'`

```
methods: {
    format(date)  {
      return format(date, "d MMM yyyy")
    }
},

<span style="color: var(--grey)">{{ format(movie.release_date) }}</span>
```

пытаюсь отформатировать данные которые получаю из api (там realese_date: 2021-03-30) и пытаюсь отформатировать их, но выдает ошибку `Invalid time value`

Comment: Попробуйте почитать документацию, в частности какие аргументы принимает format

Answer (score 0):

Потому что дату со строки нужно распарсить

```
import { format, parse } from 'date-fns'

return format(parse(date), "d MMM YYYY")
```

Вот вариант для примера через CDN (для демонстрации, что работает)

```js
function format(date)  {
  return dateFns.format(dateFns.parse(date), "d MMM YYYY")
}

console.log(format('2021-03-10'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: TypeError: 3 arguments required, but only 1 present